# use one row of two dimensional array as parameter to function

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have 2 dimensional array like this,

```
set[3][5]={{0,0,0,1,0},{0,1,0,0,0},{0,1,1,0,0}};
```

I want my program to take the one set like {0,0,0,1,0} and assign that to some variables and pass those variables as parameter for some function and do the same for other set of values.

Here is my code,

```
for(i=0;i<3;i++){
    a=set[i][0];
    b=set[i][1];
    c=set[i][2];
     .
     .
    s=somefunc(a,b,c,d,e);
}
```

Instead of doing like this, is there a way to do this? How to use a row of two dimentional array for passing as argument for function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the function expects five arguments, there's no way to do it. You can't have C magically "re-pack" a matrix row as function arguments in the call.

If the function accepts a `const int *args`, you can pass the address of the first element on the row:

```
s = somefunc(&set[i][0]);
```

since the remaining elements will follow from that address. This works since C uses [row-major order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order).

You can of course define a trampoline to do this:

```
static int call5_from_row(const int *row5,
                          int (*func5)(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e))
{
  return func5(row5[0], row5[1], row5[2], row5[3], row5[4]);
}
```

you'd use it in your original code like so:

```
for(i=0;i<3;i++){
    s = call5_from_row(&set[i][0], somefunc);
}
```

But this is just your original code with an extra function-call in the middle, it's not better.

Comment: No, function has 4 more arguements other than the array value!

Comment: @no1 No, he is passing the function pointer as one parameter, making the algorithm more generic, in case you want to do different things with the values and not just execute "somefunc" every time. If you don't need that functionality, I posted a simplified version.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, you want something like this:

```
int somefunc (int set[5])
{
  return somefunc5(set[0], set[1], set[2], set[3], set[4]);
}


int main()
{
  int set[3][5]={{0,0,0,1,0},{0,1,0,0,0},{0,1,1,0,0}};

  for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
    s = somefunc(set[i]);
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define an array (dimension equal to the number of columns of the matrix), copy the row you'd like to pass into the array and then pass it to the function.

In your specific case:

```
int i, row[5];

for(i=0;i<5;i++)
   row[i] = set[0][i];
```